# "Error $(...).modal is not a function" en Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap

Estoy intentando mostrar unos modales por pantalla cuando suceden X cosas, el problema es que me está saltando el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Jquery lo instalé mediante el comando `a`, luego lo tengo importado de la siguiente forma en el BODY, si no lo ponía así, me petaba al iniciar:

```html
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

El HEADER lo tengo así:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exercise</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    
    <!-- ANIMATIONS CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/animate.css">
    
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP 4.5.3 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/bootstrap_4.5.3.css">
    
    <!-- FONT AWESOME CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Estoy usando Angular, bootstrap 4.5.3 y tengo instalado JQuery. Jquery en el componente lo muestro de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mostrar el modal lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
          if ($.isEmptyObject(this.userService.userGetted.value)) {

            $("#failModalMessage").text("Wrong username");
            $('#failModal').modal('show');

          } else {
            if (this.password.value != this.userService.userGetted.value.password) {

              $("#failModalMessage").text("Wrong password");
              $('#failModal').modal('show');

            } else {

              localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(this.userService.userGetted.value));
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);

            }
          }
```

Sin embargo, pruebo de la siguiente forma y se muestra el modal correctamente:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#failModal">Launch modal</button>
```

Me parece extraño ya que ayer cuando apagué el ordenador me funcionaba todo como la seda, se me mostraban los modales.

He probado a reinstalar JQuery pero nada, también he mirado un montón de preguntas por ahí y no me resuelven nada. Alguna idea?

Comment: Como estas importando tus dependencias jquery y bootstrap js?

Comment: Jquery lo instalé a través del comando ```npm install jquery --save```. He actualizado la pregunta para que se vea como tengo importado Jquery y Bootstrap.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064176/typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function-with-bootstrap-modal en el link detallado se resuelve el problema presentado